# Saving an int to a file in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I have this code I got off dev.android.com...

```
@Override
    protected void onStop(){
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(levelComplete);
        fos.close();
    }
```

Supposedly this should create the file if it's not there, otherwise, it should write to it. However, I'm getting a FileNotFoundException. Help?

EDIT: Input:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
    levelComplete = fis.read();
    fis.close();
}
```

Comment: please, post the openFileInput listing here

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Also, don't forget to put the permissions in manifest file. 
Something like :

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This should help !!

Comment: I always thought `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is only needed if the file is written to an EXTERNAL_STORAGE (e.g. SDCard)...

Comment: Yes, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is needed only to write files on external storage like SDCard.

Comment: That's, ah, almost identical to what I have above?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be this that is your problem, but I just want to mention it to be sure:

If you look at the documentation for the [`openFileOutput (String name, int mode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function, the description for the `name` parameter says the following:

> *name:* The name of the file to open; can not contain path separators.

Notice in particular the part about ***can not contain path separators***. Many misses out on this one and tries to specify a complete path (such as `/sdcard/myapp/myfile.txt`), but this is not allowed. Instead you should only specify the name of the file (e.g. `myfile.txt`).

The reason for this is that `openFileOutput` opens a stream to a file which is *private* to your application (and the documentation also says that it will create the file if it doesn't exist). Because of this it will not make any sense to specify a path, since it will reside within your applications *private* area.

Comment: No, my path is just a filename. :)

Comment: @Joel Auterson: ok, we've ruled that one out then. I don't see any other obvious errors in your code, so it might be useful if you update your question to included the full error stack trace you get when trying to open the file.

Comment: Eclipse is telling me I have unhandled exceptions. Do I need to actually have the file created beforehand?

Comment: @Joel Auterson: that shouldn't be necessary. According to the documentation for `openFileOutput` (see link in my original answer), it says *Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.*.

Comment: Irritating. Is it because I'm writing an integer, do you think? I would have thought it would work regardless...

Comment: @Joel Auterson: I do not think so. But as I said earlier, it would be interesting to see *the full* stack trace from your error (as it appears in LogCat) - that might shed some more light on what is going on here. So if you could update your question to include this as well, that would be nice.

Comment: I can't actually compile the thing due to Eclipse throwing up errors within the editor.

Comment: @Joel Auterson: if you can't compile your code, how on earth do you know that you get a `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Eclipse underlines it in red and throws up "Unhandled exception: FileNotFoundException".

Comment: @Joel Auterson: huh? Eclipse cannot know whether the file you try to open exists or not without running the code. Is this is really the case, than the `FileNotFoundException` is not at all related to the actual code that tries to open the `FileOutputStream`, it has to be something else. What you say here was not at all clear from your original question (and is probably quite essential), so I suggest you write a new question where you explain this very carefully. Preferably you should also include a complete code sample so that people have a real chance of telling what might be wrong.